# How to Check if second child exsits

Tags: jquery

I am struggling with how to check if second child exists or not. If it exists then perform certrain functionality:

```
<table>
  <tr>First tr</tr>
  <tr>First tr</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How do you mean? Check the length of children? Use querySelectorAll and count the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `length` of the selector results to check the children count. You can then perform your operation or loop through each of them as well.

If you just want to check exactly 2 children, then use  `=== 2` condition. ( code added)

```js
if ($('table tr').length > 1) {
  console.log('second child exists')
}

if ($('table tr').length === 2) {
  console.log('Only two child ')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>First tr</tr>
  <tr>First tr</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just want to check if exactly second child exists. The above condition will be true if it has more than 1.

Comment: @AMobin how difficult is to to change it to `=== 2`?

Comment: @AMobin did it helped?